# Creating D3 table. If Else Statements are working for th but not for td

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, interactive

I am creating an interactive table based on Jonah's table: http://bl.ocks.org/jonahwilliams/cc2de2eedc3896a3a96d

I want the cells that meet certain criteria to be colored green and the ones that don't meet the criteria colored red. The switch is a selector menu I placed on the top-left corner. If I run this code for thead cells "th" everything works fine but if I do it for tbody cells "td" it doesn't work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
#table-location {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="selector"></select>
    <div id="table-location"></div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
// var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
//  .attr("height", 1)
//  .attr("width", 19);

var table = d3.select("#table-location")
    .append("table")
    .attr("class", "table table-condensed table-striped"),
    thead = table.append("thead"),
    tbody = table.append("tbody");


d3.tsv("VotingInformationTable.tsv", function(error, data2){

 //   }
    // // filter year
    // var data1 = data2.filter(function(d){return d.Year == '2010';});
    // // Get every column value
     var columns = Object.keys(data2[0]);
    //  .filter(function(d){
    //      return ((d != "Year"));
    //  });

    var header = thead.append("tr")
        .selectAll("th")
        .data(columns)
        .enter()
        .append("th")
            .text(function(d){ return d;})
            .on("click", function(d){
                if (d == "Year"){
                    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
                        if (a[d] < b[d]){
                            return -1;
                        }
                        if (a[d] > b[d]){
                            return 1;
                        }
                        else{
                            return 0;
                        }
                    });
                }

                else {
                    rows.sort(function(a, b){
                        return b[d] - a[d];
                    })
                }
            });

    var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
        .data(data2)
        .enter()
        .append("tr")
        .on("mouseover", function(d){
            d3.select(this)
                .style("background-color", "orange");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d){
            d3.select(this)
                .style("background-color","transparent");
        });


    var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(row){
            return columns.map(function(d){
                return {value: row[d]};
            });
        })
        .enter()
        .append("td")
        .html(function(d){ return d.value;});

    var players = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d){ return d.Year; })
        //.key(function(d){return d.Club;})
        //.key(function(d){return d.PointsNTeams;})
        //.rollup(function(d){ return d.PointsNTeams; })
        .rollup(function(a){ return a.length; })
        .entries(data2);

    var selector = d3.select("#selector");

    selector
         .selectAll("option")
         .data(players)
         .enter()
         .append("option")
             .text(function(d){ return d.key + ":" + d.value; })
             .attr("value", function(d){ return d.key; })

    selector
        .on("change", function(d){
        d3.selectAll("th")
        .style("color", function(d)
        {
            if (d == "Year") {
                return "green";
            } 
            else {
                return "red";
            }
        });
        });

});

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could color the rows that correspond to the selected year by using this :

```
selector
    .on("change", function(d){
    var v=this.value;
    rows.style("color", function(d){
        if (d.Year == v){
            return "green";
        }
        else { return "red";}
    });
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I am getting the same results as before.

Comment: Have you replaced you selector.on("change",) by mine ? It works for me.